# High-temperature microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, adc, atmega, temperature, teensy

I am looking for a microcontroller to replace a Teensy 4.0. The problem is that the Teensy doesn't cope well with high temperatures.

I realise that seeking recommendations for specific products is considered off-topic due to the risk of obsolesence.

Question:

- **Are there guidelines that would be useful to help me to find current products that would meet my requirements?**

---

The specifications I'm looking for are as follows:

- High maximum operating temperature, at least 125°C
- Minimum 13-bit analog-to-digital converter (ADC)
- Capable of handling 1000 Hz data sampling and high-frequency data shaping (~200 Hz)
- Multiple analog inputs
- Serial communication
- Powered at 5 V or less (preferably the minimum)
- I'd prefer to be able to download Arduino code onto it, or else in C
- Requires a simple assembly, not too many components

Comment: I am disappointed that people did not perform the minimal editing required to make this question acceptable and useful longer term, rather than, instead, closing it. Questions like this have the potential to attract useful answers with long term potential to help others.

Comment: OTOH, if a simple web search readily provides so many hits, it is questionable why the OP was unable to find this information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A web search using the terms [high temperature microcontrollers](https://www.google.com/search?q=high+temperature+microcontrollers&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=high+temperature+microcontrollers&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIICAEQABgWGB4yCAgCEAAYFhgeMgoIAxAAGIYDGIoF0gEJMTU3NjRqMGo0qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) turns up a number of candidate manufacturers.  While individual products on this list may become obsolete  with time, some manufacturers maintain availability for very long periods. One such is Microchip, who will still in many cases supply devices first available decades ago.

The following manufacturers (and suppliers) currently supply families of microcontrollrs (or in some cases only a few) which will operate at standard temperatures.

Digikey - [Selecting and Applying MCUs in Extended- and High-Temperature Applications](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/articles/selecting-and-applying-mcus-in-extended--and-high-temperature-applications)
A valuable discussion of high temperature aspects.

- "Your best approach is simply to use the DigiKey website and part-sorting tool as way to see which MCUs are readily available with elevated temperature support. For example, let's consider Freescale, which has a wide selection of MCUs available with 125°C capability. If you use the DigiKey keyword search and enter the terms "Freescale MCU" you get an extremely long list of products. But if you scroll to the right you can select an operating temperature range to 125°C, click the "in stock" box, and then click the "apply filters" button and you will see the product families with readily-available stock."

[This Digikey search](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/microcontrollers/685?s=N4IgjCBcoEwKwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIMY8MALCEXAAxgBsA7HA5dXGPUSrwm7bkL5MxvJgA4pdAJwL5tBXMHVVAZhXt1POjIgbDkk7XbLBtGArBXKNhTDOPbWxNdtwdXhXH06W1YIAF0iAAcAFygQAGUogCcASwA7AHMQAF8swXIQAFkAYQBVEFCsoA)
lists **14,000+ microcontrollers with rated ambient temperatures of 125 degrees C or above.**

A subset of this search should produce a number of candidates from a range of manufacturers that suit your requirement.

---

[Microchip](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/solutions/high-temperature)

40+ microcontrollers listed. **Temperature −40 to +150°C**

- "Our high-temperature technology spans all product families including microcontrollers, analog, and memory.
  **Reliability testing is performed to AEC-Q100 Grade 0 (150°C) and specified for operation up to 150°C ambient.** This enables robust applications under-hood, down-hole and in-oven. Click on the product family below to see a complete high-temperature part number listing in that family, with links to data sheets, application notes and other information."

---

[Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430F2619S-HT)

One example. There will be others

---

[Honeywell - only for the very serious](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/us/en/products-and-services/product/hardware-and-systems/microelectronics/high-temperature-microelectronics)

- "Honeywell offers a large family of high temperature electronic components on Silicon On Insulator (SOI) CMOS technology to provide extraordinary performance in high temperature applications.
  **Designed to operate continuously for at least 5 years at 225°C**, the high temperature standard electronic product family is targeted at sensor signal conditioning, data acquisition, and control applications in harsh environments. These products offer significant reliability and performance advantages over traditional silicon integrated circuits when the operating temperatures are greater than 150°C. Honeywell also provides custom high-temperature integrated circuits and package development for extreme temperature environments."

In another league!  - just to demonstrate what is available, for enough money.

[Single Package Re-Configurable Processor for Data Acquisition at 250OC](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aerobt/en/documents/learn/products/microelectronics/technical-articles/SinglePackageRe-ConfigurableProcessorForDataAcquisitionAt250DegC.pdf)

- "A high-temperature data processing device is required for applications gathering sensor data and control of
  electronics in environments which operate above 200°C. This paper discusses the process of leveraging advances in
  high temperature electronics and integrating them for new applications and improved system performance. It
  centers on the development of the 250oC High Temperature (HT) SOI CMOS process technology, several new HT
  products, and HT package technology. Honeywell integrates a HT FPGA, SRAM and EEPROM into a Multi-Chip
  Module (MCM) creating a flexible, re-configurable computing platform for sensor data processing and control
  applications at 250°C. A reconfigurable processor enables the ability to gather information from multiple sources
  and then control multiple devices with a single electronics assembly while reducing size, weight and power.
  Packaged in a small 2.2 x 0.75 inch (56 x 18 mm) MCM, the module operates at clock rates up to 10MHz from a
  single 5V supply. Although power consumption is strongly dependent on configuration, the targeted demonstration
  configuration clocked at 1MHz power dissipation is on the order of 100mW. The combination of all these
  technologies and application code to operate the module provides a significant improvement over existing
  technology for data acquisition applications."

[Extreme Design: Developing integrated circuits for -55 degC to
+250 degC](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aerobt/en/documents/learn/products/microelectronics/technical-articles/ExtremeDesignDevelopingIntegratedCircuitsFor55DegCTo250DegC.pdf)

- What Honeywell did to meet the challenge of designing g analog silicon ICs for aerospace and deep-drilling applications

---

[US Department ofEnergy "Deep Trek" program](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aerobt/en/documents/learn/products/microelectronics/technical-articles/TechnologyandToolKitDevelopmentForTheDeepTrekProgramHITEN2005.pdf) about 2003

An excellent discussion of what is involved in developing such devices.

- The motivation for the Deep Trek program is
  to support technology development that makes deep oil and gas drilling economically viable. Down hole data
  acquisition systems are necessary to make deep drilling and reservoir production cost-effective. High temperature
  encountered at great depth (>200°C) is the single biggest obstacle for electronic data acquisition systems in very deep
  wells. Electronics needed in these environments include signal conditioning, A-to-D conversion, digital processing and
  control electronics, and memory (including non-volatile memory).
  Commercial electronics are not designed for these temperatures, and conventional silicon integrated circuit
  technology is not capable of operating at these temperatures. It is well known that SOI CMOS is a viable alternative to
  bulk CMOS technology for high temperature [2]. However, most commercial SOI processes are optimized for
  consumer digital applications (i.e., optimized digital speed/power trade-off). These processes tend to be limited in terms
  of supply voltage, making analog and mixed-signal applications difficult. In addition, although junction leakage is
  reduced by SOI, sub-threshold leakage in low-voltage SOI processes may render them unusable for extreme high
  temperature because of unacceptably high standby current.
  Therefore, some tailoring of the process for extreme temperature applications is needed, first to provide capability
  for analog as well as digital applications, and secondly to deal with sub-threshold leakage in very large digital circuits
  (memory, microprocessors, etc.). ..."

Comment: I used a Microchip MCU in a 180 C situation (lamp heated environment.) Above max spec of 150 C die temp. But this was a one-time process to collect experimental data for later analysis and we could afford losses. Luckily the units survived. I can't say the same for all the EEROMs. Some made it, some didn't.